# Spark to cache a file to prevent the file being deleted while processing it

Tags: apache-spark

I have a Spark application trying to read a file. Due to lazy loading of Spark, it is possible that the file exists when `spark.read`, but the file is deleted when I actually load the file such as `count` operation.

```
// t0: file exists when initially trying to load the file
val ds = spark.read.json("s3://some-location/some-file")

// some operations on ds

// t1: the file s3://some-location/some-file is deleted from S3 by someone else

// t2: continue doing some operations on ds

ds.count // throws exception
```

Can I mitigate the problem by caching the file immediately after `spark.read`, something like

```
val ds = spark.read.json("s3://some-location/some-file")
ds.cache
ds.count // force load the file
```

Comment: Spark Don't delete any file in. any process, till you are not giving force operation. it just reads the data from the file and processes it according to defined instruction.  Might be some configuration issue with AWS.

Comment: @D-2020365 I don't mean Spark delete the S3 file, I mean while the spark application is running, someone else deletes the S3 file.

Comment: I think this issue is with s3.

Answer (score 0):

Spark doesn't read and store the data in memory, depending on the type of file you are dealing. Reading is a continuous process that happens throughout the lifecycle of the application.

If you have a problem that another application is deleting your file, I would suggest using some sort of locks, that prevents deletion of the file. It does seem s3 supports this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-lock.html (full disclosure I have never used it)